# SQL insert in taxonomy_index doesn't work

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I used the following code, but it doesn't work, and I get no errors.

```
$query = db_insert('taxonomy_index')->fields(array('nid', 'tid', 'sticky', 'created'));
$query->values(array(
  'nid' => $node->nid,
  'tid' => 53,
  'sticky' => 0,
  'created' => time(),
));
$query->execute();

dvm($query);

if (!$query) {
  dvm($query);
}
```

The output of this code is the following.

[image: query result]

```
$query = db_insert('taxonomy_index')
  ->fields(array('nid' => 27, 'tid' => 53, 'sticky' => 0, 'created' => time()))
  ->execute();

dvm($query);

if (!$query) {
  dvm($query);
}
```

This code doesn't output any error; `dvm($query)` outputs `'0'`.

```
$row = new stdClass();
$row->nid = 27;
$row->tid = 55;
$row->created = time();
drupal_write_record('taxonomy_index', $row);
```

This gives the same result of the previous code.

```
$arr[] = 55;

db_query('INSERT INTO {taxonomy_index} VALUES  (%d, %d, %d, %d)', 27, 55, 0, time());
```

It doesn't work; It outputs the following error message.

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to db_query() must be of the type array, integer given, called in D:\OpenServer\domains\boobon\sites\all\modules\backup_bike\backup_bike.module on line 214 and defined в функции db_query() (строка 2342 в файле D:\OpenServer\domains\boobon\includes\database\database.inc).

I have installed the Ubercart module.

Answer (score 1):

I think in D7, you can not use db_query() for insert operations - db_query() can be used only for Select and you should use db_insert() for insert operation.

For your 1st code bloc, perhaps the db_insert() causes 1st row with blank values - since it expects fields and values for 1st row. The subsequent $query->values() adds a second row. This may explain the blank values in dvm().

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I see here is that your db_query has to give you an error, because it's not well set :

```
db_query(
   'INSERT INTO {taxonomy_index} VALUES (%a, %b, %c, %d)',
   array(
     '%a' => 27,
     '%b' => 55,
     '%c' => 0,
     '%d' => time()
   )
);
```